# Cannot iterate over ExecutionResult

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, resultset

I have written a test, copying the official cypher query example from [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html) and adding a needed cast. Then it fails with:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11 cannot be cast to java.util.Iterator ...`. This is the code:

```java
@Test
public void testCreateWithCypher() {
  ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(db, StringLogger.SYSTEM);
  try (Transaction transaction = db.beginTx()) {
    String cypher = "CREATE (x:Person {name: 'John'})" +
                    "RETURN x";
    ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(cypher);
    Iterator<Node> n_column = (Iterator<Node>) result.columnAs("x");
    for (Node node : IteratorUtil.asIterable(n_column)) {
      String nodeResult = node + ": " + node.getProperty("name");
    }
    transaction.success();
  }
}
```

Without the cast, it will not compile, since `columnAs` returns `Iterator<Object>`. What is this `scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11` doing the by the way? I thought it [extended](http://api.neo4j.org/2.1.0-M01/org/neo4j/graphdb/ResourceIterator.html) `java.lang.Iterator`?

I just want an `Iterator<Node>` so that I can get stuff from the `ExecutionResult`. How can do that without the cast? My project uses these dependencies for `${neo4.version}` = 2.0.1:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using `org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine` instead of `org.neo4j.cypher.`**javacompat**`.ExecutionEngine`. The first one is implemented in Scala and you can't directly cast Scala objects to Java ones (AFAIK).